# Delayed gratification reward expression

Tags: popular-refrains

Is there a saying that means delayed gratification increases the eventual gratification?

Comment: "worth waiting for"?

Comment: If you ever need it, for the flip side of this (delayed pain = decreased pain) there's "[Tax delayed is money saved](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cm9VBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=%22tax+delayed+is+money+saved%22&source=bl&ots=2QEEufmI0z&sig=v5-ngCfCxzE3ZmykyB38rBFgnkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDjcnSm7PJAhUC2R4KHTq3CKoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22tax%20delayed%20is%20money%20saved%22&f=false)"

Comment: For the antithesis:  "In the long run, we are all dead"  Keynes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas Fuller [*Gnomologia: Adages and Proverbs; Wise Sentences and Witty Sayings*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3y8JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22Fortune+often+rewards+with+interest+those+that+have+patience+to+wait+for+her%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir2p3M0bXLAhVH6GMKHdAyAAkQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22Fortune%20often%20rewards%20with%20interest%20those%20that%20have%20patience%20to%20wait%20for%20her%22&f=false) (1732) includes this saying, which seems to be on point:

> Fortune often rewards with interest those that have patience to wait for her.

The idea of the saying seems to be that we can obtain better results by biding our time and waiting for a propitious moment to act than by forcing the issue prematurely through impatience.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard [**slow and steady wins the race**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slow+and+steady+wins+the+race) used as a reference to delayed gratification quite a number of times.

> It took me a while to come around to the idea of **delayed gratification**.

(Comments to *Slow and Steady Wins the Race* at [getrichslowly.org](http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2009/11/16/slow-and-steady-wins-the-race/))

> So is it always wise to **delay gratification** and play it **slow and steady**?

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=wPUWBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=delayed%20gratification%20slow%20steady&source=bl&ots=NVaufuoe_M&sig=mD-zbibzkgbeu9uJUm6GbZD-AEM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8usHju7PJAhVBlhQKHVCzCFcQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

If a saying is what you are looking for how about proverbs 13: 12 ?

' Hope deferred makes the heart sick: but when it comes it is a tree of life '